# LinkedInCommunicationFailed

Tags: android

```
final LinkedInOAuthService oauthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(consumerKeyValue, consumerSecretValue);   
    LinkedInRequestToken requestToken = oauthService.getOAuthRequestToken();
```

I am using LinkedApi library,Yesterday this code was working but today I don't know why,but its giving exception

```
LinkedInRequestToken requestToken = oauthService.getOAuthRequestToken();
```

Its giving :

```
com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
```

Comment: Hey Lookas have u any idea about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**--Solved--**
I am posting code so all my friends need not to struggle

Step 1)Get pin by using API

```
oauthService= LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(consumerKeyValue, consumerSecretValue);   
    requestToken= oauthService.getOAuthRequestToken();
    //requestToken=oauthService.getOAuthRequestToken();
    //getOAuthRequestToken(""); 
    autoToken= requestToken.getToken();  
    authoTokenSecret = requestToken.getTokenSecret();  
    authUrl= requestToken.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Log.i("Tok", autoToken);
    Log.i("Tok", authoTokenSecret);
    Log.i("Tok", authUrl);

    webview.loadUrl(authUrl);
```

Step 2)webview will show pin after login to linked in now use your pin to got access token and using access token you can get profile and update status

```
String pin = pin_edit.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("Fetching access token from  LinkedIn...");        
    LinkedInAccessToken accessToken =  oauthService.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, pin);
    System.out.println("Access token: " +  accessToken.getToken());
    System.out.println("Token secret: " +  accessToken.getTokenSecret());
    final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory =  LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(consumerKeyValue,  consumerSecretValue);
    final LinkedInApiClient client =  factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);

    Person profile = client.getProfileForCurrentUser();
    profile.setCurrentStatus("Hello all my friends ,I am missing you all"); 
    client.updateCurrentStatus("Hello all going");
```

Comment: Hello TofeeqAhmad, I had tested using your code but still i am facing same error... please can you share the code... Thanks in Advance... :)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response... i had posted this error here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573491/android-linkedin-integration-crashing-java-io-filenotfoundexception-https-ap

Comment: I did not get any idea by ur post.Download api from Linked In site and then use my code in class.If it help you then upvote this answer

Comment: and remember donot change time of machine on which you are testing this

Comment: are you taking about linkedin-j-android.jar file [library] ?

Comment: Yes i am talking about linked-j-android.jar file[library]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6005/discussion-between-bipin-vayalu-and-tofeeqahmad)

Comment: Hello bro, Can u please tell me the detail how to save the token.i have done with save preference but while i am login again with save token i have face this problem... so if any help regarding this issue please help me.....LinkedInRequestToken liToken=new LinkedInRequestToken(<token>,<token_secret> ); i will pass this paramiter

Answer (score 2):

```
AsyncTask<String, Void, LinkedInRequestToken> getMapTask = new AsyncTask<String, Void, LinkedInRequestToken>() {

        @Override
        protected LinkedInRequestToken doInBackground(String... params) {

            LinkedInOAuthService oauthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY, Config.LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET);   
            LinkedInRequestToken requestToken=oauthService.getOAuthRequestToken();

            return requestToken;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(LinkedInRequestToken requestToken) {

            super.onPostExecute(requestToken);

            String autoToken = requestToken.getToken();  
            String authoTokenSecret = requestToken.getTokenSecret();  
            String authUrl = requestToken.getAuthorizationUrl();
            Log.i("Tok", autoToken);
            Log.i("Tok", authoTokenSecret);
            Log.i("Tok", authUrl);
            openPupUpLinkedin(authUrl);

        };

    };
    getMapTask.execute();
}
```

Comment: this is my solution incase anybody needs